# What possible errors could I expect to recieve in System.Net.Mail.SendCompletedEventHandler?

Tags: .net, email, error-handling, asynchronous, system.net.mail

I am using the SendAsync method to send some emails out. What different errors could possibly be returned in the AsyncCompletedEventArgs in the SendCompletedEventHandler? Is there recommended practices for handling these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything is possible here, you might be trying to talk to a particularly cranky SMTP server.  You can't handle errors in your code, your code can't change the way the server works.  It takes a human to figure out why the server doesn't like your message.  The error codes that can be returned by an SMTP server are otherwise documented, review the [SmtpStatusCode enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpstatuscode.aspx).